# How does eBay, mail, and other apps send alerts if not running?

Tags: android, notifications

We have several apps on our android devices that signal notifications even when the device is off.   An example, if we are watching an eBay auction on our PC, and we have the eBay APP on the device, even if the device is off, we get a "chime" and a notification on the top of the display about the auction.   Another example, GasBuddy will chime a notification when gas prices are going up in our area.

How do these apps do this, even with the app actually not running?
- Are they "automatically" running in the background?
- Are they periodically, every few minutes as an example for the auction purpose, automatically logging into the internet and checking for an update?
- Is somehow the "service" such as eBay or GasBuddy "pushing" some sort of signal to the device?
- Do they have "another" app running in the background looking for notifications?

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for push notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use the concept of Push Notifications. You can use [Google Cloud Messaging(GCM)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) for push notifications.

In short how it works is, the app when launched for the very first time, or when the user logs in, registers an id with the server. The server then at a later time sends a signal to the device (using that id) using push notifications. You need to handle those push [notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) in your android app.